# Commutative Ergodic Theory

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, ergodic-theory

I've been working through some of the standard ergodic theorems for class (Birkhoff, Hopf, Chacon-Ornstein), and I'm attempting to extend Hopf's maximal ergodic theorem to the case of having commutative transformations. I was wondering if anyone could recommend possible readings that could help guide me or if anyone had some suggestions.

Thanks